# PUT errors in Vue

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to update data using laravel. I'm not sure why I can't access the PUT api. I tied so switch the api to store the data vs update and that works. I can't see anything wrong with the code.

Here is the api router

```
Route::put('product', 'ProductController@update');
```

here is the controller

```
 public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {

        $product= Product::findOrFail($id);
        $product->update($request->all());
        return ['message' => "Success"];

    }
```

Here is the vue.js

```
methods: {
      updateProduct(id){
      this.$Progress.start();
      this.form.put('api/product/'+this.form.id)
      .then(() => {
                    // success
                    $('#addNew').modal('hide');
                     Swal.fire(
                        'Updated!',
                        'Information has been updated.',
                        'success'
                        )
                        this.$Progress.finish();
                        Fire.$emit('AfterCreated');
                })
                .catch(() => {
                    this.$Progress.fail();
                });
      },
```

In the Vue component I have a modal with a form

```
<form @submit.prevent ="editmode ? updateProduct() : createProduct()">
```

The error I'm getting is 
405 (Method Not Allowed)

Comment: where you add the update data in vue ? can you add that code as well. And what's the error while using PUT ?

Comment: What error(s) are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

The error I was getting was in the api router.

```
Route::put('product/{id}', 'ProductController@update');
```